# Convert data from latin1_swedish to utf-8

Tags: php, utf

I need to convert data from old database to new one. Old database was in latin1_swedish_ci  collation and have content in cyrilic language like this

```
<p>ÐÑ€Ñ…Ð¸ÐµÐ¿Ð¸ÑÐºÐ¾Ð¿ Ð¾Ñ…Ñ€Ð¸Ð´ÑÐºÐ¸ Ð¸ Ð¼Ð¸...
```

This content with utf-8 enconding on page looks like this

```
<p>Архиепископ охридски и митрополит скопски ...
```

Which is fine. Now I need to convert all of this data into native UTF-8 content. No expirience with these, any sugg.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

And note that , this will affect existing column collations also. If you want to change default collasion to `utf8` , must change database collation. After that all new table will be `utf8`

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html),

`ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;`

However, if you have characters that cannot be converted then you will lose that data. First make a backup and try it there.