# MYSQL data corrupted on server change

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Some of the table rows are affected, while changing the server! My original database was MyISAM latin1 swedish, my new databse is InnoDB uf-8.

Text in database:-

```
1. (correct) - à¤•à¤µà¤¿à¤¤à¤¾à¤“ à¤µ à¤•à¤¹à¤¾à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¥‹à¤‚ à¤®à¥‡à¤
on conversion - कविताओ व कहानियों में पूर्ण रूचि दर्शाती है

2. (corrupted) - &agrave;&curren;”&agrave;&curren;&deg; &agrave;&curren;…&agrave;&curren;&sect;&agrave;&curren;&iquest;&agrave;&curren;• 
on conversion - à¤�à¤° à¤�à¤§à¤¿à¤� à¤µà¤¿à¤�à¤¾à¤¸
```

Any idea how to correct them ?

Till now I have tried them to convert table UTF8. Tried to re-generate backup but still same problem :(

Comment: What are the the 2 db settings? innodb utf-8?

Comment: Earlier was - MyISAM UTF-8

Comment: You should add more detail about the database types, versions, charset, table charset, how you backup the data, is there the original database available, etc...

Comment: database - 5.6.15, charset - varchar, table charset - latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: In that case you have to convert your charset from latin1 to utf-8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108550/convert-data-from-latin1-swedish-to-utf-8 Use always UTF8 by the database and by the tables and rows too...

Comment: Is there anyway to get the correct text back ? I have tried UTF8 in all. and also imported new one too. But the problem is there :(   &agrave;&curren;”&agrave;&curren;&deg; this should be -> à¤”à¤° à¤•à¤§à¤¿à¤•

Comment: If you have the original database, then you have to create an utf-8 php file, which reads the data through a latin1 connection. After that you have to put the data into an utf-8 connection with the new database. Which has utf-8 charset in its tables.

Comment: If the original table does not exist, then you have a problem. In theory the data is still there in a latin1 swe encoding under an utf-8 table, so I think it is possible to restore it, but I am not certain how. I think PHP does not have the features to do that, I tried to convert latin1 to utf-8 with your texts with `mb_convert_encoding()`, but the result was slightly different. I guess the latin1 swe is slightly different from the latin1 the converter uses, but I am not sure. I think there are more skilled ppl here, so I suggest you to wait for another response.

Comment: MySQL latin1 swe should be charset "cp1252". I tried to convert your corrupted text into utf-8 from that charset without any luck. :S

Comment: Btw. this is a possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183491/is-this-a-safe-way-to-convert-mysql-tables-from-latin1-to-utf-8 and many other questions, but it is hard to decide whether the solutions there are working on here, so I don't flag it for close.

Comment: The biggest problem is some of them are corrupted some are working fine don't know why this is happening !

Comment: Do you have the old database? In what form do you have backup?

Comment: I suggest you edit your post, and write down step by step what did you do with your database and your data. Maybe then somebody can help you. For me this is not enough. Maybe you could share a backup sample file, because I am not sure it is the same as copy-pasting your text from here. I tried conversions of `&agrave;...` from latin1 swe to other charsets, both nothing ended up with the same result. :S